# How to invert loop nesting?

Tags: c#, loops

Simplified the question, this ain't homework.

In `List<Room>`, each Room has number of people in this room. Currently I was printing room_id + person_id like so:

```
foreach(var room in List<Room>)
{
    for(var i=0;i<room.numberOfPpl;i++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("room_id={0} person_id={1}",room.id,i))
    }
}
```

Output: `room_id=1 person_id=1, room_id=1 person_id=2, room_id=1 person_id=3 ...`

Now my requirement is to loop throughout rooms first:

output: `room_id=1 person_id=1, room_id=2 person_id=1, room_id=3 person_id=1, room_id=1 person_id=2 ...`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var maxNoPpl = rooms.Max(room=>room.numberOfPpl);
for(var i=0;i<maxNoPpl ;i++)
{
    foreach(var room in rooms)
    {
        if (i < room.maxNoPpl)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("room_id={0} person_id={1}",room.id,i))
        }
    }
}
```

Not that this requires `using System.Linq;`.